# Onclick the jquery event button color not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three buttons, **Button 1 & Button 2 & Button 3**. My requirement is that if Button 2 is clicked, the background color should change using an **onclick event**. I have tried but I am not able to do this. If I click Button 2, button 1 color is changing. If I click Button 3 , Button 1 color is changing.

```js
var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
     var btn = 'button';
     var color = '#101010';
     
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "red"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="setColor()">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="setColor()">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="setColor()">Button 3</button>
```

> My Updated code

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 data: {city:city,locality:locality},
  url: "rentlocalityFilter.php",
 success:function(data){

   var htmlString='';
          $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
           var id = value.id;
           htmlString +='<a class="col-md-1 icon" style="margin-top:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="guesttt_login()"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: -11px; color: red;" id="button" id="button" onclick="setColor('+value.id+')"></i></a>';

        });

 }

 });


var count = 1;
function setColor() {
 var btn = 'button';
 var color = '#101010';

    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count = 1;        
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        count = 0;
    }
    }
```

Comment: you can only give 1 element the id `button`.

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. Also please clarify what exactly you want to achieve, it's a bit unclear.

Comment: Find many error in the code Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Id's on a Html-page have to be unique.

what you need to do is give ID's like:

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="setColor('button1')">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" onclick="setColor('button2')">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3" onclick="setColor('button3')">Button 3</button>
```

and change your javascript-Code:

```
var count = 1;
function setColor(_btn, color) {
 var btn = _btn;
 var color = '#101010';

    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count = 1;        
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<button onclick="setColor(this)">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="setColor(this)">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="setColor(this)">Button 3</button>

var count = 1;
function setColor(btn) {
    var color = '#101010';
    // doesn't need getElementById anymore, use btn directly because we gave 'this'
    if (count == 0) {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count = 1;        
    }
    else {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLp03bvz/2/)

### Edit 1:

Your last update make sense but still not enough to make a solution because we still don't know about `value`, I can just say that you should also give Id like this, `id="'+value.id+'" onclick="setColor('+value.id+')` or you can remove this line and use `jquery`

```
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>

var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this); 
    var color = '#101010';
    if (count == 0) {
      btn.css("backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF");
      count = 1;
    } else {
      btn.css("backgroundColor", "red");
      count = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

[jquery solution](https://jsfiddle.net/sL8k1f1m/5/)

Hope helps,

Comment: Onclick event i want pass one JS variable dynamically,How can pass here

Comment: You got still errors, there can't be multiple items with same id. @GhulamMohayudin

Comment: @Berkay, Can you please see updated code, from there i want to pass id dynamically and color change activity

Comment: Your updated answer not enough for me, why because , you are passing value.id, for me i want to pass this & value.id,How can do this, can you please update your answer

Comment: Can you please check my updated answer,After getting success response i am creating htmlString,from there i am writing onclick event called setColor,fro here i am passing id value

Comment: @ are you there ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this

```
var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn) {

     var color = '#101010';
        var butn = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            butn.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            butn.style.backgroundColor = "red"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

You also need to pass value.id with in id attribute

```
htmlString +='<a class="col-md-1 icon" style="margin-top:10px;cursor:pointer"> <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: -11px; color: #8bc34a;" id="'+value.id+'" onclick="setColor('+value.id+')"></i></a>'
```

Comment: Onclick event i want pass one JS variable dynamically,How can pass here

Comment: No id is required in my case

Comment: you can remove the id attribute it works on ( this ) which is the instance of the current element

Comment: Can you please see updated code, from there i want to pass id dynamically and color change activity

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin bro just take your time to simplify and make a better commented code and it will be accepted .. :) up vote 1 (y)

Comment: let me add what you want

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working properly like ,suppose i have 4 button . if i am clicking first button means color is changing,next i am clicking second button means color not changing ,next i am clicking third  button means color is changing,next i am clicking fourth button color is not changing how can resolve this @ Ghulam Mohayudin

Comment: @Ghulam Mohayudin, are you there?

Comment: then there might be some problem with your id

Answer (score 1):

Look this example, is working and have less code.
Just pass the element clicked to the function and with toggleClass you can change the background color.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```js
   
    function setColor(elem) {
     $(elem).toggleClass('active')


    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button"  id="button1" onclick="setColor(this)">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" onclick="setColor(this)">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3" onclick="setColor(this)">Button 3</button>
<style>.active{background-color:red}</style>
```

Comment: @Rot, Can you please see updated code, from there i want to pass id dynamically and color change activity

Comment: The updated code came from where? Where's the var htmlString  asigned? or used? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Html code like this:

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="setColor('button1')">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" onclick="setColor('button2')">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3" onclick="setColor('button3')">Button 3</button>
```

JavaScript code like this:

```
var count = 1;
function setColor(btnId) {

 var color = '#101010';

    if (count == 0) {
        btnId.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        count = 1;        
    }
    else {
        btnId.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

I hope help you.